# jQuery Knockout - dynamic add and remove html attributes

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a  html element which looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'data-text': hasText && textMessage }"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var viewModel = {
    hasText: ko.observable(false),
    textMessage: ko.observable()
};
```

What i want, is to dynamically add and remove the 'data-text' attribute and populate it with the value of `textMessage` property.

Right now, it outputs the boolean result of the `hasText && textMessage`:

```
<div data-text='0' />
```

or

```
<div data-text='1' />
```

How can I dynamically remove or add the attribute and populate it with the data?

Comment: is hasText depends on some checkbox select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a computed observable property and then bind that to your `data-text` attribute:

```
var viewModel = {
    hasText: ko.observable(false),
    textMessage: ko.observable(),   
};
// the funny syntax is because viewModel is an object literal
viewModel.textAttr = ko.computed(function(){
        // you need to return null or undefinied then KO won't the attribute
        return viewModel.hasText() ? viewModel.textMessage() : null
});
```

And then your binding will look like:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'data-text': textAttr }">Div</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp5Wz/).